# Composer: Can not get my custom repository from my server

Tags: git, repository, composer-php

I wanted to create my own repository for composer. Let's call it myrepo.git. So a created and put composer.json on root of my repo which has only minimum like this:

```
{
    "name": "My/Myrepo",
    "description" : "My repository",
    "version": "1.0.0",
}
```

I put this to my git server so I'm able to get it from git by this:

```
git clone git://myserver.com/myrepo.git
```

But I want to get it from composer. So I created composer.json on my workstation:

```
{
    "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git://myserver.com/myrepo.git"
    }
    ]
}
```

An after that I called composer install. Everything finished without error but my repository does not fatched. I have no idea why. When I try to add there some repository from github it fill fetch that without problem, but my repository not. No error. Just nothing. So output look like this:

```
composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)       
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

So I thing I have something wrong in my repository (myrepo.git). But if so I don't understand I have no error in composer install command. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

- If you have a `composer.lock` file `composer install` will read dependencies from this file and install.
  -> In this case you should run `composer update My/Myrepo` instead.
- You have tagged the version within the `composer.json`. Do you have tagged the version in GIT, too? I don't know what happens if not.
  The GIT tagged version should be the same or you could leave the `version` property out (recommended):

  https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#version

  > Note: Packagist uses VCS repositories, so the statement above is very
  >   much true for Packagist as well. Specifying the version yourself will
  >   most likely end up creating problems at some point due to human error.
- If you have something with the same name + version already installed you have to force the install by deleting the already installed library (by our own risk") `rm -Rf vender/My/Myrepo`. Eventuelly there is the a better approve to force.